# Optimising Delaunay triangulation algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, delaunay

Dear Community Members,

I’ve been working recently on Delaunay triangulation implementation in cpp. While I’ve algorithm that works.. it’s terribly slow (100 objects are computed in about ~16 seconds).

Algorithm is basing on brute force approach. Given a finite set of points:

- I’m iterating through each points three times, checking, if I can
  create a triangle from those points;
- From those three points, I’m creating circle, that goes through those    points;
- I’m iterating through whole set of points fourth time, checking if    created circle, contains any point different from those three 
  mentioned above.
- If no additional points are within circle, I assume that triangle    created from those three points is valid.

Like I mentioned, algorithm is direct implementation of on Delaunay triangulation described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation. It’s working “flawlessly” but its slow.

Any ideas/suggestions about logic that could speed it up (if possible, without changing logic entirely)?

Comment: You'll have to change the logic if you want acceptable speed. Whatever trick you use, n^4 is going to be very slow, sensible algorithms are n log n.

Comment: could you have a predefined set of circles for some range of triangles. Then just see if your points match one of these

Comment: I'm going to give a general tip that too few people know: You don't need to take the square root when checking if a point is in the circle.

Comment: That page lists four algorithms. How about trying one of those?

Comment: also the bottleneck is usually in wrong lists usage with too much reallocations or insert movements ... resulting in even much much worse complexity ....

Answer (score -1):

Thank You all for quick feedback.

I’ve done some additional research and sadly, it seems the most optimal way to reduce time complexity is to rewrite existing algorithm entirely.

For others who could have similar issues, sample approaches are described here: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/274/proj.html

Comment: this should be comment instead of answer.